# Required Parameter is missing grant_type Google oauth2.0 AngularJS and Cordova inappbrowser

Tags: angularjs, google-oauth, inappbrowser

I am using Cordova's inappbrowser and integrating Google oauth2.0.  Once I get the authorization code I make a post request to get my token. NO MATTER what I try I always get a 400 error with "Required Parameter is missing grant_type".  I'm encoding uri, I'm setting the right headers but to no avail... can anyone help?

```
                    $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
                    params:{code:authorization_code[0],
                        client_id:options.client_id,
                        client_secret:options.client_secret,
                        redirect_uri:options.redirect_uri,
                        grant_type:'authorization_code'},
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    }
                }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function(data, status,headers,config){
                    console.log('data, status, headers,config',data,status,headers,config);
                    deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
                });
```

and this is the output from the Chrome dev Console when I try to make the request

[image]

Request URL:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id=736406995874-oh7o4cmaju3jgprllln97nf0p3pc1f91.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=ysgrIV6mJXxritfXnRcclV_U&code=4%2FnITDK731NhavPePthrVA1eX8LHFC.ojUX9K7DpBYaEnp6UAPFm0HWDS5njgI&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost

Request Method:POST

Status Code:400 Bad Request

**Request Headers**

**POST** https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id=xxx-oh7o4cmaju3jgprllln97nf0p3pc1f91.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=xxx&code=4%2FnITDK731NhavPePthrVA1eX8LHFC.ojUX9K7DpBYaEnp6UAPFm0HWDS5njgI&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost HTTP/1.1

**Accept:** application/json, text/plain, */*

Origin: file://

testing: testing

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SCH-I535 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36

**Query String** Parameters
client_id=xxx-oh7o4cmaju3jgprllln97nf0p3pc1f91.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=xxx&code=4%2FnITDK731NhavPePthrVA1eX8LHFC.ojUX9K7DpBYaEnp6UAPFm0HWDS5njgI&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost

**Response Headers**
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Mon, 14 Jul 2014 06:35:22 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: GSE
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong post request. The `params` property is used to set any additional request parameters to be appended to the URL query string. The `params` property is a JavaScript object with one property per request parameter to add.

[Here for your reference.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm)

Answer (score 0):

**You just need to send data/params in serialized** (for `angular` use `$httpParamSerializer`)

```
 $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
                params:$httpParamSerializer({code:authorization_code[0],
                    client_id:options.client_id,
                    client_secret:options.client_secret,
                    redirect_uri:options.redirect_uri,
                    grant_type:'authorization_code'}),
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                }
            }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(data, status,headers,config){
                console.log('data, status, headers,config',data,status,headers,config);
                deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
            });
```