# Google Oauth Authorization failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-ruby-client

I am trying to use the 'google-api-ruby-client' gem in a rails app to be able to request a user for access to their Google Drive. I am successfully navigating to the request permissions page where a user clicks accept. I have a callback function in a controller that captures the code that is returned upon a user clicking accept. I am then trying to fetch an access token. This is where I am getting hung up. I am getting this error:

[image]

My current controller code looks like this:

```
require 'google/api_client'

class GoogleDriveController < ApplicationController

  def initialize
    @client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => '????',    :application_version => '1.0.0')
  end

  def auth
    @client.authorization.client_id = ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"]
    @client.authorization.client_secret = ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"]
    @client.authorization.redirect_uri = ENV["GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI"]
    @client.authorization.scope =     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    authorize_url = @client.authorization.authorization_uri
    puts "https://#{authorize_url.host}#{authorize_url.path}?#{authorize_url.query}"
    render json: {google_auth_url: "https://#{authorize_url.host}#{authorize_url.path}?#{authorize_url.query}"}
  end

  def callback
    @client.authorization.code = params[:code] if params[:code]
    access_token = @client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
    @drive = @client.discovered_api('drive', 'v2')
  end

end
```

Any help or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check below 3 links. They got the same error msg as you did.

[Google OAuth2: Required parameter is missing: grant_type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030312/google-oauth2-required-parameter-is-missing-grant-type)

[Required Parameter is missing grant_type Google oauth2.0 AngularJS and Cordova inappbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730716/required-parameter-is-missing-grant-type-google-oauth2-0-angularjs-and-codova-in)

[Google OAuth2 error - Required parameter is missing: grant_type on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960087/google-oauth2-error-required-parameter-is-missing-grant-type-on-refresh)

Comment: The problem is that he's using an API built by Google to fetch the access token, not manually POSTing over HTTP like the other responses